# With Selenium 4.12, how can we use Driver manager in offline mode or keep chrome driver locally instead of downloading each time in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've a requirement where my Selenium python code will execute and server won't be having any internet connection, so how can I use selenium driver manager in offline mode by specifying driver path available in local drive.

I tried using this code in python but it didn't work & throwing error.

Line#1        print(config().get_chromexecutable_path())
Line#2        service = ChromeService(executable_path=config().get_chromexecutable_path())
LIne#3        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

Line#1 is printing correct path as ->
drivers/chromedriver
But error is saying ->

service = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x000001D2DD159280>, options = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x000001D2DD1593D0>

```
@staticmethod
def get_path(service: Service, options: BaseOptions) -> str:
    path = service.path
    try:
        path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
    except Exception as err:
        msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
        raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err

    if path is None or not Path(path).is_file():
```

> ```
>       raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to locate or obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']}")
> ```

E           selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to locate or obtain driver for chrome; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting
/errors/driver_location

venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py:44: NoSuchDriverException

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium-4.8.3, and how about try the following code:

```
cur_path = str(Path(__file__).parent)
chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(os.path.join(cur_path,"Depends","chromedriver.exe"), options=chrome_options))
```

as you see in the code, the downloaded package chromedrier is located in the ./Depends/ folder.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was doing one mistake in my first approach which I figured out.          service = ChromeService(executable_path=config().get_chromexecutable_path())            
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)                                                          For chrome driver path I was not using .exe & was using only "drivers/chromedriver"  once I changed to "drivers/chromedriver.exe" It started working.